# React change color dependent on value

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx

I have a custom UI component. How do I style the values accordingly? For example "Not Started" should be red, "Verified" green and "In Process" orange.

I am using CSS modules.

```
<Box
label={foo}
description={verificationCompleted ? "Verified" : !verificationStarted ? "Not Started" : "In Process"}
onClick={bar}
/>
```

Comment: try to add class based upon condition

Comment: It would be cleaner to make two functions that return a description and a color conditionally in my opinion, you can either change the style object or do it with classes like mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

In your Box component create a function that takes the description value as a parameter inside the function just creates a switch statement and returns the color value.

```
const checkColor = (description) => {
switch (description) {
  case "Not Started":
    return "red";
  case "Verified":
    return "green";
  case "In Process":
    return "orange";
  default:
}};
```

And after that, the function returns your desired color. you can use it in style.

```
<p style={{ color: `${checkColor(description)}` }}>{description}</p>
```

An example is created on code sandbox. if needed just visit [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/async-hooks-4zlc5u)